# PHP results as a link?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm using this code to display the latest 5 entries from a database on my website. Now i want to show the $result as links to ex. pedigree.php?id=**$resultname$**&db=pedigree&gens=5. How to do that?

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM pedigree ORDER BY PedigreeId DESC LIMIT 5");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        echo $row[0].'<br />';

?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You already have the code to display it in a table.  Is it really that far a stretch to figure out how to apply it to a URL?

Comment: What is the content of `$row[0]`? Also, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions - they are deprecated and no longer supported in the latest version of `PHP`. Look at `mysqli_*` or using `PDO` prepared statments.

Comment: I'm really a newbie and copy/pasted this code from somewhere else on the internet. The content of $row[0] is a name.

Comment: column names are usually case-sensitive in MySQL if your table is setup to be that. So, in a fetch row such as `['Name']` or `['name']` as suggested below, stand to fail. check for errors on your query http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php - I also don't know why they suggested row names like `Name` or `name` being mixed, and whether it really exists in your table or not.

Comment: Plus, do read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 your code is open to a serious SQL injection using a GET method like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link in `HTML` has the syntax `<a href="url.php">Link Text</a>`.

So:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<a href='pedigree.php?id={$row[0]['Name']}&db=pedigree&gens=5'>{$row[0]['Name']}</a>";
}
```

FYI, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions as they are **deprecated and no longer supported in PHP 7.***

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't shows anything to me? Regards

Comment: Changed it to     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<a href='pp_pedigree.php?id={$row[0]}&db=pedigree&gens=5'>{$row[0]}</a><br>";
 } and now it works! ;) THANKS .. what do i need to do for changing mysql_?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic question , You should serach google for it first :) .. anyway here is the answer

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedigree ORDER BY PedigreeId DESC LIMIT 5");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

            echo '<a href="pedigree.php?id='.$row['name'].'$&db='.$row['PedigreeId'].'&gens='.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a><br />';
    }


?>
```

**One Advice: Do not use mysql_* functions ,use mysqli or PDO .. mysql_* functions are depreciated in updated versions of PHP**

Comment: Thanks a lot but this gives me an empty output?

Comment: what is your database structure ? can you show us ?

Comment: Found a way with the soultion above! Thanks anyway a lot for your help

Comment: `['Name']` and `['name']` in a fetch row are not the same in many cases. If the row is mixed case, then `['name']` will fail.

Comment: yeah , my bad! "N" should be uppercase here

Comment: It's an honest mistake ;-)